# Incorrect push(maybe). Post request doesn't work. Postman doesn't see my raw data

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

I started do my server and found problem with post requests: input data(in post request) doesnt add to my array(adding only {}).

I added images(black interface - my postman app which works incorrect, white interface - correct example which i would like)

**My code of main file:**

```
    /*global require*/
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'phone',
        price: 300,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'tablet',
        price: 700,
    },
];

app.get('/products', (req, res) => res.json(products));
app.post('/products', (req, res) => {
    products.push(req.body);
    res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Working on port 3000...'));
```

**[image: Raw data which used in postman for post requests:]**

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "computer",
    "price": 3000
    }
```

*Response data which i got:*

```
{}
```

*I would like get data like this:*

```
    {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "computer",
            "price": 3000
            }
     

**My get request works good. After using of Get request i would like get this:**

{
            id: 1,
            name: 'phone',
            price: 300,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'tablet',
            price: 700,
        },
 {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "computer",
        "price": 3000
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
in the black interface you are sending the input as text. Change it to json.